# `Leaderboard` tab not showing in Google Play Games while `Achievements` tab is there

Tags: java, android, libgdx, google-play-services, google-play-games

I have enabled and added a leaderboard and achievements to my game. The leaderboard tab is not being displayed in Google Play Games, but the achievement tab is. I've read that the app needs to gain enough attention? What does that mean exactly? And how am I supposed to test this feature?

**This is an example from the web**

It shows the achievements tab, but as you can see, to the right, is a Leaderboards tab.

[image: Leaderboards]

Comment: By "the app needs to gain enough attention", it means that your app should reach a certain amount of users. Referencing through the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards#creating_a_leaderboard) there is no part that says that it should be the case in order for the Leaderboards tab to show up. What is in the documentation is that after adding the Leaderboard and publishing it correctly it should appear and should be readily available. Please check if for possible oversight. Good luck!

Comment: @gerardnimo Thank you. It still doesn't show up. It also doesn't display the `Features` section in the `About` tab.

Comment: @Z0q, i am going to play devil advocates here. have you check the name of  your achievement board is 100% the same? (no capitals difference, etc). Google service system is case sensitive. I had something similar happening to me. It has nothing to do with the attention as per my game has the leader-board from the beginning (and I only had 10 users).

Comment: @Kanekotic Thank you for your comment. Where do I need to check the name? I use the ID of the leaderboard in my code from the `Get resources` option. The Google Play Games Developer Console states that there are 13 scores posted to the leaderboard, but it is still not visible in Google Play Games on my Android phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted Google support directly. They told me that my app did not pass their threshold of Google Play Games users. They decided to keep it a secret where the threshold is.

Comment: Have this tab in Play Games and icon in Google Play appeared for your app? I currently have 21K users signed in my game and still do not see neither of them :(

Answer (score 2):

For your question it seems that you are trying to Find LeaderBoard in achievement Tab

LeaderBoard and Achievement are not shown Simultaneously u need to show LeaderBoard differently by calling

```
startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(
                getApiClient(), getResources().getString(
                        **R.string.your_leaderboard_id**)), REQUEST_LEADERBOARDS);
```

and For achievement it is

```
startActivityForResult(Games.Achievements.getAchievementsIntent(
                        getApiClient()), REQUEST_ACHIEVEMENTS);
```

Comment: I prefer not to show the leaderboard by calling a function inside my code, but rather want it to be displayed in Google Play Games without entering the app first.

Comment: When I open the Google Play Games app, I navigate to my app and it shows Achievements there.