# Achievements and Leaderboard in Google Play Games

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games

I have made 2 games, with the first being [[Hangman PlayStoreLink]](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gfaiers.hangman&hl=en_GB) [[code GitHubLink]](https://github.com/gfaiers/Hangman) and the most recent being [[Reactions PlayStoreLink]](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gfaiers.reactions&hl=en_GB) [[code GitHubLink]](https://github.com/gfaiers/Reactions).

Both games are working perfectly aside the Achievements and Leaderboard in Hangman.  When making Reactions I copied the code across from Hangman for all the google services, so in that respect it's exactly the same.

**Issues with Hangman:**

- Doesn't save achievements
- Doesn't award achievements when milestones are reached
- Doesn't load leaderboard when pressing the Leaderboard button
- When loading your Play Games app it doesn't display "My Achievements" section, although this does display for Reactions

I'd expect to have the issue in both if it's not working in one of them, as I've done exactly the same in both.

Has any one else experienced this before?  Can anyone help me sort this out?  I want the players to be able to receive their achievements!

I've included links above to the code and Play Store links so you can test this and see the issues for yourselves.

Answer (score 0):

Well, make sure that you create your achievement by following the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/achievements#creating_an_achievement).

Go to the **Google Play Developer Console** entry for your game under the **Games with Game Services** tab, then select the **Achievements** tab on the left, and click the **Add Achievement button**. After that, simply fill out the information required for this achievement, then **SAVE**.

For the [leaderboards](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards#creating_a_leaderboard), it is likely the same steps.

Also, double check if you properly follow the steps in [Creating Client IDs](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling) and [Configuring Services](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/configuring).

> Once you publish your game, take **NOTE** that if you are using
>   **leaderboards** and **achievements** in your game, these game features may
>   not be immediately reflected under your game's listing in the Google
>   Play Store until your users start earning achievements and posting
>   scores.

For more information, check these thread

- [`Leaderboard` tab not showing in Google Play Games while `Achievements` tab is there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178395/leaderboard-tab-not-showing-in-google-play-games-while-achievements-tab-is-t?rq=1)
- [How to show the google play game achievements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34409334/how-to-show-the-google-play-game-achievements)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've done this already, if you're able to view the code or download the app. See if you're able to receive the achievements, or get on the leader board.

Comment: Ok, I will try it if I have some time this week.

Comment: by the way, is this app not yet publish?

Comment: It is published, both are.

Comment: Well, according to this [link](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/testpub#publishing_your_game_changes) "Note: If you are using leaderboards and achievements in your game, these game features may not be immediately reflected under your game's listing in the Google Play Store until your users start earning achievements and posting scores." maybe that is the issue?

Comment: Hangman has a lot more downloads than Reactions, and that's all up and running already? Reactions only has 5 downloads so far.  Hangman is over 60+ (both very low still). On Hangman you can play, be awarded with the achievements then close and reopen it and get them all again.